# Why am I getting duplicate(?) outputs for my slurm jobs

Tags: python, slurm

I've started working with Slurm, so I've written a simple script to try it out.

Basically, it intends to submit 10 jobs as a job array, and each job just echos its index (0, ..., 9).

But I'm a bit confused about why I'm getting 2 logs per job.

E.g., I'm getting {job array id}_x_0_log.out and {job array id}_x_1_log.out, where x is in range(10).
Their contents are perfectly identical except for two things:

1. The 0_log.out files have local_rank and global_rank as 0(2) in JobEnvironment, while the 2_log.out files have 1(2).
2. The timestamps differ by about a millisecond.

The first thing seems relevant, but I can't make sense of it, and I haven't had much luck looking for answers online.

Here's the script, in case it's relevant.

```
import subprocess
import submitit
from pathlib import Path


def run_command(command):
    """Run a CLI command and capture the output
    """
    return subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, check=False)


def submit_tasks(log_folder, commands):
    """Submit multiple jobs, each running a CLI command, as a job array
    """
    executor = submitit.AutoExecutor(log_folder)
    executor.update_parameters(
        slurm_array_parallelism=3, slurm_partition="{partition name}", cpus_per_task=1
    )
    jobs = executor.map_array(run_command, commands)

    return [job.result() for job in jobs]


def test_slurm():
    """Submit a bunch of simple echo commands to Slurm and print outputs
    """
    work_dir = Path(Path.home(), "workspace")

    # echo 0 ~ echo 9
    commands = [f"echo {x}" for x in range(10)]

    results = submit_tasks(work_dir, commands)

    with open(Path(work_dir, 'test.log'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        print(results, file=f)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_slurm()
```

test.log has 10 entries as expected.

So why am I getting two logs instead of just 10 {job array id}_x_log.out files?

Again, very new to Slurm, so I'm not 100% sure if I've used the terminology correctly, and/or if I've provided the most relevant information. I'd be happy to provide more info.